# Accessing colorbox Iframe content with jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe, jquery-selectors, colorbox

I tried accessing the content of an iframe, generated by the jquery colorbox plugin, for hours without success.

Heres my code:

```
    $(".ListView li a").colorbox({ 

iframe:true,
width: "50%",
height: "50%",
opacity: 0.5,
onComplete: function() { 
alert("complete");
$("iframe").contents().find("p").css("color","#f00");   
}
});
```

It loads a file and displays it. so fine.  The alert message is also thrown, when the iframe ist loaded completey. But I cant access the element within the frame through the jquery selector. Nothing happens to all p element inside the iframe.

Neither

```
    if($("iframe").contents().length > 0)
{
alert("exists");    
}
```

nor

```
    if($("iframe").length > 0)
{
alert("exists");    
}
```

are successful. There is no other iframe on the page, I also tried to insert the class name.

For "normal" iframes, inserted directly into html and not generated by colorbox, my function are working.

Thank you

The code generated:

```
<div id="colorbox" class="" style="display: block; padding-bottom: 50px; padding-right: 50px;    top: 128px; left: 476px; position: absolute; width: 902px; height: 207px;">
<div id="cboxWrapper" style="height: 257px; width: 952px;">
<div>
<div style="clear: left;">
<div id="cboxMiddleLeft" style="float: left; height: 207px;"></div>
<div id="cboxContent" style="float: left; width: 902px; height: 207px;">
<div id="cboxLoadedContent" style="display: block; width: 902px; overflow: auto; height: 187px;">
<iframe class="cboxIframe" frameborder="0" name="cbox1334265249803" src="qtest.html">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<body>
<a href="#">Link</a>
<p>Formatted Text</p>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
</div>
<div id="cboxLoadingOverlay" style="float: left; display: none;"></div>
<div id="cboxLoadingGraphic" style="float: left; display: none;"></div>
<div id="cboxTitle" style="float: left; display: block;"></div>
<div id="cboxCurrent" style="float: left; display: none;"></div>
<div id="cboxNext" style="float: left; display: none;"></div>
<div id="cboxPrevious" style="float: left; display: none;"></div>
<div id="cboxSlideshow" style="float: left; display: none;"></div>
<div id="cboxClose" style="float: left;">close</div>
</div>
<div id="cboxMiddleRight" style="float: left; height: 207px;"></div>
</div>
<div style="clear: left;">
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; width: 9999px; visibility: hidden; display: none;"></div>
</div>
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable" style="display: none; z-index: 1000; outline: 0px none;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-box-trash-dialog">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With iframes, onComplete actually fires as soon as the iframe element is added to the document.  If you want to query the contents, you have to wait until the DOM is ready.  There is no way for the parent document to know when the iframe's DOM is ready, it can only listen for the window's onload event.

But, you can tell colorbox to wait and fire the onComplete function after the iframe's onload event has been triggered by setting the fastIframe property to false.  Example:

```
$('a.example').colorbox({iframe:true, fastIframe:false, width:500, height:500})
```

Of course this all assumes the iframe is originating from the same domain as the parent, and there are no security limitations preventing you from accessing the iframe's contents.

Comment: Thank you very much! After googling "oncomplete colorbox" I found this page: http://groups.google.com/group/colorbox/browse_thread/thread/77e89cc514d43abf

where you have explained it to somebody else. Now it works awesome.

Answer (score 0):

There is a corss-browser solution to access the contents of an iframe, you can read about it [here](http://roneiv.wordpress.com/2008/01/18/get-the-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript-crossbrowser-solution-for-both-ie-and-firefox/).

Also, you can access the contents of your iFrame with jquery, read more [here](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).

Both solutions find your iframe by ID, so you will need an id to use these solutions. I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I know how to access an IFRAME. It works fine with jquery (by ID, by Class, by Tag) when I write <iframe src... directly into html. But it doenst work when the Iframe is generated by the colorbox plugin.

Comment: Is the $("iframe") command giving you any iframes? If not, then the iframes are not generated yet when you try to access their contents.

Comment: Yes you are right, the oncomplete event is fired, when the overlay appears, but at this time the iframe is not yet created.  There are some similar questions in the web, nobody knows a working solution...